# Найти максимальный элемент массива

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Найти максимальный элемент в массиве ai (i=1, , n), используя очевидное соотношение max(a1, , an) = max[max(a1, , an–1), an]. Использовать рекурсивную и нерекурсивную функцию. Рекурсией решил, а вот циклом никак не придумаю как реализовать.

Comment: Ответов на похожие вопросы в SO очень много

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы серьезно? 8-/

```
int max = a1;
for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
    if (max < a[i]) max = a[i];
```

Comment: а разве это соответствует заданию?Это же обычный поиск макс. элемента.....

Comment: А как иначе? Смотрите - вы работаете по формуле max(a1...ai) == max(max(a1..ai-1), ai) - сравнивая с очередным значением. Инвариантом цикла является то, что переменная `max` содержит максимум для подмассива (a1..ai). Все **строго** по вашей рекурсивной формуле - только без рекурсии, как вы и заказали! P.S. Не обижайтесь, но так и вспоминается "Мещанин во дворянстве" - "А я и не подозревал, что 40 лет говорю прозой!!" :) Да, этот "обычный поиск" тютелька в тютельку ложится в вашу рекурсивную формулу :)

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
int max_from_sub(const int* arr, const size_t start, const size_t size)
{

    int max = arr[start];
    for (size_t i = start + 1; i < size; ++i)
        if (max < arr[i]) max = arr[i];
    return max;
}

int array_max_element(const int* m, const size_t n)
{
    int max = m[0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
        max = std::max(max_from_sub(m, i, n), max);
    return max;
}
```

Или без функций:

```
int max = arr[0];
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        if (max < arr[j]) max = arr[j];
```